# Why does OS need Fork()?

Tags: unix, operating-system, kernel

I am learning by myself introduction of OS, I have the following two questions:

(1) Since `Fork()` system call is used to duplicate the current process for the sake of multitasking, I'd like to see a example that shows without forking, we will not have such multitasking? In other word, I would like to see an example (or an external link) that shows how important Fork() is.

(2) Does`Zombie` process exist because of the child's process crash?

Thank you very much

Comment: Fork is just the eunuchs way of creating a new process. Most operating systems have no equivalent (unless emulated). Eunuchs is rather weird in the way it treats processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for `fork`, `fork` is just the Unix way of creating process. Older and different systems used something different as `spawn` (Vax/VMS) for example.

Zombies are just traces of died processes, this is useful for parents to be aware of died children after having been busy. Remember that in Unix, a process that terminates let its parents be aware of the cause of its termination. So there is a need to let died process store that information somewhere, Unix way is to maintain a process entry named zombie as that process is reduced to this small entry and no other resources are linked to.

Comment: Windows doesn't have fork either (outside of the POSIX/UNIX subsystems/Linux userland subsystems).